# Tell git subtree to use destination path for squashed commits

Tags: git, git-subtree

When you add a subrepo using `git subtree add --prefix third_party/libfoo upstream_libfoo master --squash` it will:

1. Create a new root commit containing the contents `master` from the `libfoo` repo.
2. Create a merge commit with `HEAD` and that new root commit as parents. In this merge commit all of the files from the root commit are moved from `/...` to `/third_party/libfoo/...`.

The fact that the files are moved during the merge commit creates some issues:

1. You can't rebase the root commit & merge. Even with `--rebase-merges` Git will get confused because it tries to create a normal merge, not a merge that also moves files.
2. You can't easily diff between `master` and the root commit (or a later squashed commit). It *kind of* works, but the fact that all the files have moved confuses things massively. Especially if you've also added/removed files.

Is there any way to make `git subtree` store the files in its squashed commits at the same path that they will be merged into? It seems like such an obvious thing to do.